# Kendo Grid Row click change color

Tags: jquery, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with the following code :

```
var data = <?php echo $model->over_view; ?>;
        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: data,
                pageSize: 10,
                sort: { field: "metric", dir: "asc" }
            },
            dataBound: function () {
                $('td').each(function () {
                    if($(this).text() == 0){
                        $(this).text('.');
                    }
                    if ($(this).text() == 'Bad') {
                        $(this).addClass('critical')
                    } else if ($(this).text() == 'Good') {
                        $(this).addClass('ok')
                    } else if ($(this).text() == 'Suspect') {
                        $(this).addClass('warning')
                    } else if ($(this).text() == 'Idle') {
                        $(this).addClass('idle')
                    }
                })
            },
            //rowTemplate: '<tr class="#: classification ==\"Good\" ? "discontinued" : "" #" data-uid="#: uid #"><td>#: classification #</td><td>#: MAC #</td> <td>#: f_Auth #</td><td>#: f_Assoc #</td><td>#: f_EAP #</td><td>#: f_EAPOL #</td><td>#: f_Data #</td><td>#: f_DHCP #</td> <td>#: f_Unk #</td><td>#: metric #</td></tr>',
            sortable: true,
            resizable : true,
            pageable: true,
            toolbar: kendo.template($("#filterDeviceType").html()),
            columns: [
                { field: "classification", title: "Device Health",headerAttributes:{ style:"text-align:center"}},
                { field: "display_mac", title: "Devices", width: 150,headerAttributes:{ style:"text-align:center "}, template:"<a target=\"_blank\" href='"+$("#visualize-url").val()+ "?trace_id=" + $("#trace-id").val()+"&mac="+"${MAC}&perspective=${type}'>${display_mac}</a>" },
                { field: "f_Auth", title: "Authentication Failure",headerAttributes:{ style:"text-align:center"} },
                { field: "f_Assoc", title: "Association Failure",headerAttributes:{ style:"text-align:center"}},
                { field: "f_ReAssoc", title: "Re-Association Failure",headerAttributes:{ style:"text-align:center"}},
                { field: "f_EAP", title: "EAP Failure" ,headerAttributes:{ style:"text-align:center"}},
                { field: "f_EAPOL", title: "EAPOL Failure",headerAttributes:{ style:"text-align:center"}},
                { field: "f_Data", title: "Data Failure",headerAttributes:{ style:"text-align:center"}},
                { field: "f_DHCP", title: "DHCP Failure",headerAttributes:{ style:"text-align:center"}},
                { field: "Data", title: "Data Packets",headerAttributes:{ style:"text-align:center"}},
                { field: "Total", title: "Total Packets",headerAttributes:{ style:"text-align:center"}}

            ]
        });
```

The second column in the grid "Devices" is a hyperlink with each row-item pointing to a particular page. I want to add the functionality, whereby if a user clicks on a row item, the kendo grid remembers the click and changes the color of that row item accordingly(from blue to maybe violet, like google does in its search page)
How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without even worrying about the kendo framework. All you have is a table and when you click the link you want to highlight the row. So here is what you can do.

```
$("#grid tr a").on('click',function(){
  $("#grid tr.activeRow").removeClass('activeRow'); //remove previous active row
  $(this).closest('tr').addClass('.activeRow');//set current row as active
});
```

So what we have done is we bind a click event to all the anchor tags inside the table, And when it is clicked we find the closest `tr` and apply the class `activeRow`. Now we have to specify the CSS rule to change the color for this class.

```
tr.activeRow td{
  background-color: violet;
 }
```

---

**Edit 1:**

> I only want to change the color of that row element( the hyperlink ), not the entire row.

to change only the `td` of the anchor tag you can do this.

```
$(this).closest('td').css('background-color','violet');
```

Else you can assign a class

```
 $(this).closest('td').addClass('activeTd');
```

And css rule like

```
 td.activeTd {
   background-color: violet; 
 }
```

> Also, where do i put this code?

you have to put the jquery in your grid `databound` event.

Comment: I only want to change the color of that row element( the hyperlink ), not the entire row. Also, where do i put this code?

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. It would be nicer if I were able to change only the color of the href link, rather than the entire cell block.

Comment: ok that can be done too... just change the css rule to this `td.activeTd a{ color: violet; }`

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the code
`.k-grid th.k-state-selected, .k-grid td.k-state-selected, .k-grid tr.k-state-selected > td { color: #292b2c; background-color: #cecece !important; }`
and it worked for me.